# My SIGNED INT is casted to UNSIGNED when I do a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, casting, integer

I'm trying to `SUM()` with UNSIGNED INT in MySQL. When I join another table, the SIGNED INT becomes an UNSIGNED INT.

```
SELECT `weight` FROM `article_vote`
 LEFT JOIN `vote` ON `vote`.`id` = `article_vote`.`article_id`
```

returns:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

However, `SELECT weight FROM vote` returns:

```
1
1
1
1
-1
1
1
-1
-1
-1
1
```

Any ideas?

--

**EDIT**

Those 11 rows are the total records in the table, so there are not any ORDER or LIMIT.

---

EDIT

TABLE CREATE:

```
CREATE TABLE `vote` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `resource_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `submited_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_5A108564A76ED395` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `vote_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `article_vote` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_8F6C754A62922701` (`anecdote_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `article_vote_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `article` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `article_vote_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `vote` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Could you show us results of these 2 queries: `SELECT count(weight) FROM vote` and `SELECT count(weight) FROM article_vote LEFT JOIN vote ON vote.id = article_vote.article_id` ?

Comment: Both return 11, which the total of records in my table, I know where you want to come to :) but this is the full data.

Comment: What is the structure of the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the negative weights are being reordered to come later in the result set (after the LIMIT clause that the standard MySQL client applies by default).

Comment: the returns is the full table, 11 records